# Download GitHub repository without cloning it?

Tags: git, github

I am behind a firewall and I cannot use Git from the command line to clone a GitHub repository. However I can use Chrome to access the web repository.

How can I download the `.git` repository from the web platform?

The only option is the master.zip download which does not contain any Git files.

Comment: Is cloning a repo over HTTPS also blocked `git clone https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git`?

Comment: You can download using SSH or HTTPS as well.

Comment: Unfortunately yes... Any methods that do not use port 80, NTLM and fake the user-agent of Chrome cannot access to internet.

Comment: If port 80(http) is allowed it is very likely that port 443(https) is allowed, too. If NTLM is the problem, have a look at at [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: That’s a very terrible firewall if it doesn’t allow HTTPS connections…

Comment: and most likely a social problem. I know this is not solving your issue but either you are doing something wrong or your admin is kind of ... picky. Read: Please talk with your IT stuff to solve the issue on another level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download the zip, but this will not include any history.

If you want the history you have to clone the repository.

Cloning using https should work fine even with a proxy:

```
https_proxy=http://company-proxy:port git clone https://github.com/...
```

You can probably find the correct proxy-settings in your browser.

If your proxy really insists on NTLM you might have a look on [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/).

---

Alternatively a solution featuring a private computer and an USB stick might be another option.

Comment: I never tried with `https_proxy` before. This time I get a `Recived HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT`. I suppose my proxy does not allow the CONNECT method. I had this issue when I played with cntlm.